# I can protect you against several things

Tags: riddle, word

My first puzzle.

> As I am, I can protect you against failure.
>
> Remove a letter, I can protect you against cold.
>
> Remove another letter, I can protect you against hunger.

What word am I looking for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Cheat

As I am, I can protect you against failure.

> Cheat (to avoid failure)

Remove a letter, I can protect you against cold.

> Heat

Remove another letter, I can protect you against hunger.

> Eat

Comment: That's it, well done.

Answer (score 7):

Could the answer be

> TEACHER

---

> TEACHER
>
>  HEATER
>
>  EATER (or maybe CATER or CARTE?)

Comment: Good idea, but I wasn't thinking about reordering the letters, should have specified that.

Answer (score 7):

I thought

> Heart

As I am, I can protect you against failure.

> Heart (resilience/determination in the face of failure)

Remove a letter, I can protect you against cold.

> Heat

Remove another letter, I can protect you against hunger.

> Eat

Comment: Not to mention, a healthy <one of those> protects against <one of those> failure!